# Is there any way to wrap a `TabActivity` inside a `Fragment`?

Tags: android, android-activity, fragment, tabactivity

I've got to modify an existing Android application which actually has a `TabActivity` as launcher.

Due to the new purpose of the application we need to wrap that activity into a fragment in order to show it `onclick` of a button. That button will be inside the NEW launcher activity which could show different fragments.

Is there a way to wrap that `TabActivity` inside a `Fragment`?